# How can I send raw post data with python?

Tags: python, variables, http-headers, http-post, brute-force

I'm trying to post data to a web page using python.
There is a game on facebook, and the invite codes are combinations of 5 letters.
I wrote a script that wrote all the combinations of letters to a txt file.

Here is the data I need to post.
http://pastie.org/2409481

This cookie 'bbbbb' will end up being a variable and will loop through all the possible combinations of 5 letters.
[code]invite_code%5D=bbbbb[/code]

Comment: Neat, thanks for giving us your Facebook session cookies.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module? If not, please do so. If so, then please explain why using `urlopen()` didn't work for you.

Comment: just open a socket and write that thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Requests](http://pydanny.blogspot.com/2011/05/python-http-requests-for-humans.html), a wrapper for urllib2 (I believe). Ripping one of the examples off that page:

```
# This example cooked up by me!

import requests
post_data = {"amount":10000, "service":"writing blog posts"}

r = requests.post('http://example.com/api', post_data, auth=('user', 'pass'))

print r.status_code
print r.headers['content-type']

# ------
# 200
# 'application/json'
```

You should be able to set anything you want for `post_data`.